# How to share someone else's answer here as a short post?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question in stackoverflow regarding simulation of [suicide burn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59589776/simulation-of-suicide-burn-in-openai-gyms-lunarlander) and I also got a [wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59729706/996366) from William Miller as well. I think the answer posted in stackoverflow is more relevant here and might help many space fans here. How should I share his answer as a post here?

I am thinking of creating a post mentioning the problem I was facing and how William Miller's answer solved that problem and linking his stackoverflow answer's link to the post without the code. Is this kind of post allowed here?

Comment: From time to time people will post a short question as a way to post an answer that they feel will be of interest to the community, and as long as it's done well and on-topic I haven't seen any complaints. If it were me, in this particular case, I'd do something a little different though. I'd post the solution in the question and ask about further improvements or ways to modify or even ask for someone to independently verify the results in a different simulator. That may serve your purpose but it also gets others in the community much more involved than just posting a self-answered question.

Comment: But probably your way is okay, let's see what others think though.

Comment: Asking in question format would be more appropriate, as you said it would increase interactivity from community. Thank you for your input

Comment: If you are interested you could post a short answer summarizing what you did, and if there are no objections, in a few days accept it.